# Problem about sets of integers

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Given 15 pairwisely different integers. Pat wrote all sums of 7 integers and Vova wrote all sums of 8 integers from this set. Can the set of sums of Pat be equivalent to the set of sums of Vova?

I'm really stuck on this one.  Tried some stuff involving  set theory,  but can't proceed from it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by equivalent?

Comment: I assume that by *equivalent* you mean *equal*. Is the set restricted to positive integers, or can it include zero and negative integers as well?

Comment: Any integers. Also negative and 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Try $\{-7,-6,\ldots,6,7\}$.

Comment: Anything symmetric, too, I think. For example, $\{-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1\}$ should also work. I don't know if there's anything else, though.

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to show that they need to sum to $0$ and that the median (middle number) should be $0$. I don't know if it's a sufficient condition, though.

Comment: Is it proven by induction? Im trying to prove it through induction but cant. Or by considering all sums and writing them out?

Comment: Symmetry.  For any subset $S$ of size $7$, $f(S) = \{-t: t \notin S\}$ is a subset of size $8$ with the same sum.

Answer (score 2):

first of all the sum of the given 15 pairwise integers is even, since the sum of the first 7 numbers is equal t the sum of the last 8 numbers. you can put the zero on the set with 8 integers to simplify the computations.

Let set with 7 integers= A,
$let A={a,b,c,d,e,f,g}$ and say $a+b=z$, for some integer z and $(a+b)=(c+d)=(e+f)$ then the sum of the elements of set A is $3z+g$.

Let the next set be = T, $let T={h,i,j,k,l,m,n,0}$ and say $h+i=z-1$ for some integer z same with the first set. and $(h+i)=(j+k)=(l+m)$ and $n=g+3$, then the sum of the elements of T is $3(z-1)+g+3 = 3z+g$

a sample set would be
$A={1,9,4,6,3,7,5}$ and $B={10,-1,11,-2,21,-12,8,0}$
in this example i let $z=10$

so my answer to the question would be yes!

Answer (score 0):

If the set is symmetric about $0$, then the sum of entire set is $0$. It follows by taking the complement of the set of 7 numbers summed, then negating the values, we have a set of 8 numbers which sum to the same as the 7. Hence "symmetry about $0$" is a sufficient condition.

The sum of the 8 largest members must equal the sum of the 7 largest members, otherwise the sum of the 8 cannot be matched. Hence the middle ranked number must be $0$. This is a necessary condition.

However "symmetry about $0$" is not a necessary condition. The set $\{-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8\}$ has the desired property. The minimal and maximal sums for the 7 member sets and 8 member sets are both $-28$ and $29$. If a set does not have the maximal sum then we can create another set with the sum increased by $1$ by either replacing $6$ with $8$ and decrementing one of the other elements, or by incrementing an element. Hence all numbers can be summed to, for either size set.